# Ошибка при установке ARCH Linux

Tags: linux, vps, archlinux, kvm

Я пытаюсь установить Arch Linux на VPS сервер KVM от провайдера firstbyte.ru
Я скачал с официального сайта образ iso ARCH Linux и добавил этот образ в панель управления VPS сервера по следующей инструкции: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=oIbrMDwr_sc

Я начал установку (показалось меню выбора системы и я выбрал её). Но я встретил ошибку:
"

```
running hook Larchiso_pxe_nfs]
Mounting ’ /dev/disk/by-label/ARCH_202304’ to ’/run/archiso/bootmnt’
Waiting 30 seconds for device /dev/disk/by-label/ARCH_202304 .
ERROR: ’ /dev/disk/by-label/ARCH_202304’ device did not show up after 30 seconds.
Falling back to interactive prompt
You can try to fix the problem manually, log out when you are finished
sh: can’t access tty; job control turned off
[rootfs 1#
```

"
Далее в поле ввода нельзя ничего ввести (даже меняя раскладку клавиатуры).
Я пытался гуглить эту ошибку но варианты решения проблемы в основном требуют чтобы команды вводились. А их у меня вводить нельзя.
Прошу помощи, как можно решить мою проблему. Заранее благодарю.[image: введите сюда описание изображения]